# Как обновить div элемент при нажатии на кнопку не обновляя страницы?

Tags: ajax, cors

Как обновить `div` элемент без перезагрузки страницы. При нажатии кнопки добавить. Я знаю что это реализуется с помощью Ajax но ни как не могу понять как именно.

Например когда я нажимаю на кнопку добавить товар, чтобы обновлялся элемент итоговая сумма.

Comment: $(div).html("ваш html")

Comment: ("ваш html") как именно тут параметр? Не понял работу скрипта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

function getTitle(text) {
  return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}

function makeCorsRequest() {      
  var url = 'https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('не поддерживается');
    return;
  }

  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
     title;
    
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('В ответ на ошибку произошла ошибка, вызвавшая запрос.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="makeCorsRequest()">Изменить значение</button>
</div>
```